# Calculate rows with same title

Tags: r, dictionary, calculated-columns

Since my other question got closed, here is the required data. 
What I'm trying to do is have R calculate the last column 'count' towards the column city so I can map the data. Therefore I would need some kind of code to match this. Since I want to show how many participants (in count) are in the state of e.g Hawaii (HI)

```
zip     city         state  latitude    longitude   count
96860   Pearl Harbor    HI  24.859832   -168.021815 36
96863   Kaneohe Bay     HI  21.439867   -157.74772  39
99501   Anchorage       AK  61.216799   -149.87828  12
99502   Anchorage       AK  61.153693   -149.95932  17
99506   Elmendorf AFB   AK  61.224384   -149.77461  2
```

what I've tried is

```
match<- c(match(datazip$state, datazip$number))>$
```

but I'm really helpless trying to find a solution since I don't even know how to describe this in short. My plan afterwards is to make choropleth map with the data and believe me by now I've seen almost all the pages that try to give advice. so your help is pretty much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what is `datazip$number`? The sample of your data is the end result, or the input to your problem?

Comment: the sample is the input data and datazip is the name of the input data and in a previus version I wrote number instead of count.so it should be count now. sorry

Comment: so what is the output? What would your output look like?

Comment: my output would be a column containing the states (but only 1 time each state now i have a differnt amount of each state) and another column calculating all the numbers together that are in the column count( for that specific state) e.g state, count ; HI ,(36+39); AK, (12+17+2)

Comment: please write the sample output. The longer the discussion goes, the more I do not understand what are you trying to get.

Comment: I managed to make it please see below. sorry for the inabilty to write my question so everybody understands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# I read your sample data to a data frame
> df
    zip          city state latitude longitude count
1 96860  Pearl_Harbor    HI 24.85983 -168.0218    36
2 96863   Kaneohe_Bay    HI 21.43987 -157.7477    39
3 99501     Anchorage    AK 61.21680 -149.8783    12
4 99502     Anchorage    AK 61.15369 -149.9593    17
5 99506 Elmendorf_AFB    AK 61.22438 -149.7746     2

# If you want to sum the number of counts by state
library(plyr)
> ddply(df, .(state), transform, count2 = sum(count))
    zip          city state latitude longitude count count2
1 99501     Anchorage    AK 61.21680 -149.8783    12     31
2 99502     Anchorage    AK 61.15369 -149.9593    17     31
3 99506 Elmendorf_AFB    AK 61.22438 -149.7746     2     31
4 96860  Pearl_Harbor    HI 24.85983 -168.0218    36     75
5 96863   Kaneohe_Bay    HI 21.43987 -157.7477    39     75
```

Comment: yes the middle one is the right thing but all I need in the end to something like this http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/11/choropleth-challenge-result.html would be just the state and your count 2 which appears as often as the state appears. but thank you very much. could you also give me a hint on how I map this. Are the state abreviations in the package maps?so that I could refer to maps to highlight the right states?

Comment: well R counts the number but doesn't open a new column with the name count2 is there a way to do that cause I can't find he count2 data anywhere

Comment: you need to assign this result to a data.frame, either the same one or another one. It doesn't automatically update the original. So something like `result <- ddply(...`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `aggregate` would be a nice and simple solution for you:

```
df
    zip          city state latitude longitude count
1 96860  Pearl Harbor    HI 24.85983 -168.0218    36
2 96863   Kaneohe Bay    HI 21.43987 -157.7477    39
3 99501     Anchorage    AK 61.21680 -149.8783    12
4 99502     Anchorage    AK 61.15369 -149.9593    17
5 99506 Elmendorf AFB    AK 61.22438 -149.7746     2

aggregate(df$count,by=list(df$state),sum)
  Group.1  x
1      AK 31
2      HI 75

aggregate(df$count,by=list(df$city),sum)
        Group.1  x
1     Anchorage 29
2 Elmendorf AFB  2
3   Kaneohe Bay 39
4  Pearl Harbor 36
```

Comment: Not particularly. He would still have to merge it back to the original `data.frame` because all the other information (lat, long etc) are necessary for the choropleth map. That's why I used `transform` rather than `summarize`.